# How to rotate image in 25-degree increments? Android animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this xml code for animation. I need the image to rotate 25 degrees every half second.
But image rotate 360 degrees and stop. What i do wrong?

My task is to make a spinning loading image. Maybe it can be done in a different way?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toDegrees="24" />
    <rotate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromDegrees="24"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toDegrees="48" />
    <rotate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromDegrees="48"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toDegrees="72" />
    <rotate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromDegrees="72"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toDegrees="96" />
   // and many more "rotate" up to android:toDegrees="360"
</set>
```

Comment: They all have the same startOffset, shouldn't they step up?

Comment: startOffset is necessary to show twitching, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you image have to rotate 25 degree every half second to rotate  360 degree it take 7200 milliseconds. So you can try this approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    android:duration="7200"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Comment: This will be a smooth turn. I want it to move like a clock hand, twitching.